# NodeJS Logger: Remove trailing newline

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, newline, fs

I'm trying to build a custom NodeJS logger, that logs data to a file.

To append data, I use [`fs.createWriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) with the `a` flag.

```js
var fs = require("fs");

var stream = fs.createWriteStream("./test.log", {
   encoding: "utf-8",
   flags: "a",
   autoClose: true
});

// Data to log to file
var data = {
   timestamp: new Date().toJSON(),
   message: "OK"
};

// Write data
stream.write(JSON.stringify(data) + "\n");
```

Logging a few times results in a file looking like this:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-08-25T17:45:27.733Z","message":"OK"}
{"timestamp":"2020-08-25T17:45:34.820Z","message":"OK"}
{"timestamp":"2020-08-25T17:45:41.142Z","message":"OK"}
(Heres a newline, StackOverflow removes them)
```

My problem is, I don't know how to remove the trailing newline.

I thought about adding the newline before each log entry, but this requires me to detect the beginning of the file (I didn't find a way to do this).

What's the best way to remove the trailing newline, if that is even possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if file is empty:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var stream = fs.createWriteStream("./test.log", {
   encoding: "utf-8",
   flags: "a",
   autoClose: true
});

// Data to log to file
var data = {
   timestamp: new Date().toJSON(),
   message: "OK"
};

// Check if file is empty
var stats = fs.statSync("./test.log");
var isEmpty = stats["size"] == 0;

// Write data
stream.write((isEmpty ? "" : "\n") + JSON.stringify(data) );
```

Comment: That would mean that every single entry is in the first line, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In that case you need to check if file is empty, if not prepend the newline

Comment: Thank you very much, I have found a solution thanks to you. :)

Comment: I've edited my answer; is your solution similar to it?

Comment: It is. I'll accept your answer nevertheless, thanks again!